# Perl - Hash of Arrays across Module

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am a bit new to Perl and I need some help regarding moving my Hash of Arrays across Modules.

Currently I have a db module that stores an array like so:

```
    sub getSourceCriteria {

    my($self) = shift();
    my($sourceId) = shift();
    chomp $sourceId;

    my(%criteria) =();
    $logger->debug("Getting records for Source ID: " . $sourceId);
    $dbh=DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:StkSkrnDB', 'RTETET', 'XXuser01',{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 }) || \ 
               $logger->err_die("Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr\n");

    my($sth) =    "select a.criteria_id, a.criteria_type, a.criteria_props,a.generalcriteria_id,b.field_id ";
    $sth = $sth . "from t_criteria a, t_sourceMapping b where a.generalcriteria_id = (select generalcriteria_id from t_sourcecriteria where source_id =?) ";
    $sth = $sth . "and a.criteria_id=b.criteria_id";


    my($qry) = $dbh->prepare($sth);
    $qry->execute($sourceId) || $logger->error("Could not query for Source Criteria: $DBI::errstr\n");
    my(@row)=();
    my($tempCount) = 0;

    while ( @row = $qry->fetchrow_array ) {
        $tempCount = scalar @row;
        $logger->debug("Size of retrieved SQL Array : $tempCount");
        $criteria{$row[0]} = \@row;
        ##@{$criteria{$row[0]} } = \@row;


  }

  return %criteria;
}
```

And I have a seperate perl script that reads the SQL output from the code above:

```
    foreach my $criteria (keys %criterias) { 
        @temp = exists( $criterias{$criteria} ) ? @{ $criterias{$criteria} } : ();
        ##my $tempStr = exists( $criterias{$criteria} ) ? "Yes" : "No";
        $arraySize = scalar @temp;
        $logger->debug("GENERALCRITERIA_ID is $GENERALCRITERIA_ID and size of array is $arraySize and $temp[0]");
        $genCrit_ID = $temp[$GENERALCRITERIA_ID];
        $logger->debug("Criteria ID $criteria has Gen Criteria ID $genCrit_ID");
        if (0!=$generalCriteria_ID || $generalCriteria_ID != $genCrit_ID ) { ## test for uniqueness
            $generalCriteria_ID = -1;
        }
        else {
            $generalCriteria_ID = $genCrit_ID;
        }
    }# do something with $key and $value 
    $generalCriteria = $generalCriteria_ID;

}
```

The problem is I keep getting 0 as the retrieved array size( 2nd snippet) even though when I store the array ( in the 1st snippet ) I check and get the actual array size.

Please any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Added more code in the DB interface code.

Comment: Having the reader parse chunks of code obviously torn out from the middle of something larger without any clear explanation is not a great way to present your problem. You should come up with a minimal, yet clear and *self-contained* (= runnable) sample that exposes the problem. It's not unlikely that in attempting to produce one, you'll solve your problem yourself.

Comment: I honestly felt that the chunk of code I extracted would be enough to deduce an answer as I am certain that its my unfamiliarity with the Perl language that prompts the error. I am willing to add more of the code to aid any analysis.

Comment: Note I wrote "minimal", not "maximal". :-) Seriously, try heeding this advice, you'll find the solution yourself. Has helped me a thousand times already. A minimal example that evidences the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the problem was so it was a bit difficult to 'minimalise' the code. But I will take your advice on reconstructing minimal versions of code to try and solve a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you are assigning to `@row` and then storing a reference to that array.  However, each time the loop iterates, you are replacing the contents of `@row` without declaring a new array.  So at the end, each of your references point towards the same thing.

In your code here:

```
my(@row)=();
my($tempCount) = 0;

while ( @row = $qry->fetchrow_array ) {
    $tempCount = scalar @row;
    $logger->debug("Size of retrieved SQL Array : $tempCount");
    $criteria{$row[0]} = \@row;
    ##@{$criteria{$row[0]} } = \@row;
}
```

Each time the while loop iterates, you assign new values to the `@row` array.  But since the `my(@row)=();` line occurs outside of the loop, the `@row` array is always the same.  So each time you assign to the array, you are changing what is stored in all of the references you have already taken.

To fix the problem, you need to declare a new array for each iteration.  The simplest way to do this is to move the declaration into the while condition:

```
my($tempCount) = 0;

while ( my @row = $qry->fetchrow_array ) {
    $tempCount = scalar @row;
    $logger->debug("Size of retrieved SQL Array : $tempCount");
    $criteria{$row[0]} = \@row;
    ##@{$criteria{$row[0]} } = \@row;
 }
```

Now each time you take the reference `\@row` you will be getting a reference to a new array.

---

If your `$qry->fetchrow_array` method returned an array reference, you would not have had the issue:

```
my $row;
while ($row = $qry->fetchrow_array) {
    $logger->debug("Size of retrieved SQL Array : ".@$row);
    $criteria{$$row[0]} = $row;  # already a reference
 }
```

But I would still write that as `while (my $row = ...` in my own code, since keeping scopes small is a good thing.

Comment: Believe it or not, I added the pragmas for the files ( after some earlier leg shootings) and it still does not resolve the problem. I have added the whole code snippet for the 1st code snippet to give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it worked. Thanks immensely for the additional explanation using the code snippets.

Comment: Quick question: Why didn't the `while ( @row = $qry->fetchrow_array ) ` re-initialise the array though? I would have imagined that the statement would cause a new reference to be given by the `fetchrow_array` function. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Kris => assignment to an array will fill the array with elements, but it does not change the actual container (which is what you take a reference to).  The only way to get a new container is with a `my`.  See the update to the answer for the way you probably thought things would have worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric. A very thorough lesson on Perl. The reason why I love SO.Thanks again.